# How to Debug This? Wp7 app crashes on load....but only sometimes

Tags: windows-phone-7

I have a windows 7 phone app that I made(that passed certification) but for some reason it randomly will just crash on load.

It seems to happen when I have no wifi connection, so I disabled it but sometimes it crashes and sometimes it does not crash.

I tried to put a try/catch around all the startup code but still it just crashes.

Anyone have any advice on how to test this?

Comment: There is a network testing kit that comes with the windows phone SDK. Have you tried that yet?

Comment: No, Where do I get it?

Comment: Without knowing what the crash details are, we cannot accurately answer your question. What I would try is to look in your App.cs file to see if you have any uninitialized data that is inside the App class that may be referenced before something valid has been created. It could also be a XAML markup error which are difficult to trace. Could you provide a little as to what error you are getting?

Comment: That's the problem. I don't know what the error is, I don't why it is crashing. App works 99% of the time it just seems if I am out with my phone and want to use my app when there is no wifi my app crashes. Yet when I try to recreate by turning off wifi on the phone at home it works. No crash reports for any other users using my app.

Comment: Please post your startup code.